# My Classic ASP script contains both lines that require 32bit enabled and disabled application pools

Tags: asp-classic

I collect mail addresses from database and send mails using old Classic ASP. JMail requires 32Bit mode disabled in application pool.

```
Set sender = Server.CreateOBject("JMail.Message")
```

Recently I've added Oracle DB to collect more mail addresses and noticed the code below requires an application pool with 32Bit mode enabled:

```
  Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.35.200)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYDB)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=MYNAME;Password=MyPass;"
```

It looks like a weird dilemma. What would be the workaround/solution in my case?

Comment: Can you not install the Oracle OLEDB Provider for 64 bit?, the only reason that connection will have to be 32 bit is because the provider isn't registered in the 64 bit registry.

Comment: Installing Oracle is messy so I've replaced email component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change to an ASP Email component that does not have the conflicting requirement. Personally, I've used ASPEmail. It's a [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1CAGGAB_enUS615US615&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ASPEmail) away :).

Comment: Charset & SMTP authentication features require premium version which one costs 220 USD.

Comment: Or just use CDO which comes with Windows server, you don't need a third party component.

Comment: Personally never found I needed to use a 3rd party e-mail component. CDO has always sufficed as @John recommends.

Comment: CDO is awesome... my environment hosts a legacy ASP app on a newer server that does not support CDO.

Comment: Has CDO been discontinued? What version of Windows Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've learned very well & used CDO years later. Here is my code:

```
<%


  Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory. 
  Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network). 

  Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
  Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
  Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

  dim objEmail
  Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")= cdoSendUsingPort 

  'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
          objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="mail.domain.com"

  'Server port
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpAuthenticate") = cdoBasic 
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "info@domain.com"
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "thepassword"




  objEmail.BodyPart.Charset = "Windows-1254"
  'objEmail.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 
  'objEmail.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"


   'objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/SaveSentItems") = TRUE

  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
  objEmail.From = "My Name <myname@domain.com>"
  objEmail.To = "The Name <name@targetmail.com>"
  objEmail.Subject = "CDO Test"
  objEmail.Textbody = "This is a message." 

  objEmail.HTMLBody = "<h1>This is a message.</h1>"
  objEmail.Send

  Response.Write "OK"      

%>
```